# SBT 1.0 crash - java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch

Tags: scala, sbt

After installing SBT 1.0.1 on Windows 10, running any sbt command causes the error below. This is identical to error reported in the [sbt git issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3471), but I already have JDK 1.8.0_144 installed.

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

>sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
"C:\Users\****\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.1"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 162
Exception Details:
  Location:
    scala/util/matching/Regex.unapplySeq(Lscala/util/matching/Regex$Match;)Lscala/Option; @216: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2bc6 000a 2bb6 00ef c700 07b2 0052 b02b
    0x0000010: b600 f2b6 00f3 2ab6 0054 4d59 c700 0b57
    0x0000020: 2cc6 000d a700 c92c b600 f799 00c2 bb00
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed after removing a folder pointing to an older version of the JDK from the Path environment variable. The latest Oracle installed version of java.exe was earlier in the path, however I suspect that it was going to the old folder to find javac.exe for some of the steps sbt was running. I also had a JAVA_HOME environment variable set to the older JDK and removed that for safe measure.

Comment: Could you add some more details here? I'm having the same issue and pointing JAVA_HOME at the latest JRE doesn't fix anything. The only line on my Path variable that is relevant is C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

Comment: to anyone else that finds this thread, make sure you remember to close and reopen your command line prompt after you make changes to environment variables

Comment: plambre - The Oracle\Java\javapath points to java.exe, but doesn't cover javac.exe. At the a DOS prompt try "where java" and "where javac". I'm guessing that javac will be on an older JRE path.

Comment: @strke1683 - nope - i have this same error and both those commands point to a java jdk install as does my JAVA_HOME which points to the same jdk

Comment: @plambre How did you fix this in the end?